# I need a csv file with 1 million entries

Tags: csv, storage

I want a sample `csv` file of about `1 million` entries in it. From where can i get that ,can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [Majestic Million CSV](https://blog.majestic.com/development/majestic-million-csv-daily/) which is free.

If you don't mind paying a small fee you can try [BrianDunning.com](https://www.briandunning.com/sample-data/)

Answer (score 14):

Make your own...

```
perl -E 'for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++){say "Line $i,field2,field3,",int rand 100}' > BigBoy.csv
```

**Output**

```
Line 0,field2,field3,58
Line 1,field2,field3,4
Line 2,field2,field3,12
Line 3,field2,field3,39
Line 4,field2,field3,41
Line 5,field2,field3,18
...
...
Line 999998,field2,field3,67
Line 999999,field2,field3,62
```

---

Or use the `Faker` package in Python. Here to generate fake (dummy) names and addresses:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Synthesize dummy address CSV
# Requires: pip install Faker

from faker import Faker
fake=Faker('en_GB')   # Use different locale, e.g. 'de_DE' or leave blank for USA
Faker.seed(42)        # Omit this line if you want different data on each run
print('firstname, lastname, street, city, postcode, Email, telephone')
for _ in range(10):
    first  = fake.first_name()
    last   = fake.last_name()
    street = fake.street_name()
    city   = fake.city()
    zip    = fake.postcode()
    email  = fake.ascii_safe_email()
    tel    = fake.phone_number()

    print(f'{first},{last},{street},{city},{zip},{email},{tel}')
```

**Output**

```
firstname, lastname, street, city, postcode, Email, telephone
Ruth,Griffiths,Smith dam,Lake Janiceland,S0A 3JW,moorefrancesca@example.net,+44191 4960637
Joan,White,Sam square,Cookberg,N11 1QQ,samuel78@example.org,0141 496 0184
Teresa,Hurst,Mellor squares,North Irenebury,BT3 6LT,ben55@example.org,(029) 2018 0419
Heather,Thompson,Ben mountain,Dixonside,N03 5RL,kellykirsty@example.net,+441214960376
Carly,Hale,Davidson summit,Fionachester,S5D 8UD,taylorcarl@example.net,(0116) 4960691
```

---

Or to generate fake (dummy) URIs, IP addresses and MAC addresses:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Synthesize dummy IP address and MAC addresses
# Requires: pip install Faker

from faker import Faker
fake=Faker()
Faker.seed(42)        # Omit this line if you want different data on each run

print('URI, IP, MAC')
for _ in range(10):
    URI = fake.uri()
    IP  = fake.ipv4_public()
    MAC = fake.mac_address()

    print(f'{URI},{IP},{MAC}')
```

**Sample Output**

```
URI, IP, MAC
http://walker.com/,203.75.32.207,d8:10:0f:2f:6f:77
http://www.santos.org/posts/app/privacy.html,216.228.82.113,4f:6e:ac:34:2f:c2
https://baker.com/,146.195.110.208,b9:62:23:17:74:94
http://www.ramirez-reid.com/,101.107.68.129,88:24:57:7d:53:ec
```