# generate large csv with random content in bash

Tags: bash, unix, csv

I am trying to generate a large csv with random content in bash. My machine has 6 cores and 12G ram but my script (see below) takes 140 seconds for only 10k lines with 3 columns.  Is there any way to optimize this script?

Are there considerably faster ways of generating random csv files in other languages?

```
#!/bin/bash

csv="foo\tbar\tbaz"
start=$(date)
for i in `seq 1 $1`
  do rand=$(($i * $RANDOM))
  str0="$$"$i
  str1=$( echo "$str0" | md5sum )
  randstring1="${str1:2:8}"
  randstring2="${str1:0:2}"
  csv="$csv\n$randstring1\t$randstring2\t$rand"
done
end=$(date)
datediff=$(( $(date -d "$end" +%s) - $(date -d "$start" +%s)))
echo -e $csv > my_csv.csv
echo "script took $datediff seconds for $(wc -l my_csv.csv) lines"
```

Comment: This is clearly going to be _much_ faster in a compiled language. At the very least, you should minimise the number of calls you make to external tools. I'm not sure about the performance implications but you can also just do `echo "$randstring1\t$randstring2\t$rand"` in the loop and redirect it to the output file like `done > my_csv.csv`

Comment: [Mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com/) has an API you might be interested in.

Comment: Can you show 3-4 lines of output please?

Comment: Have a look here too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252963/i-need-a-csv-file-with-1-million-entries/29254156#29254156 It takes 0.6 seconds to generate 1,000,000 lines.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: 

foo     bar     baz
7c36ba55        53      24062
e175d0a8        ec      43464
c8b88c21        35      96759
01e90926        4b      18820
082c39f7        0d      107945


and so on...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To replace this script fairly precisely (format-wise), you could use

```
hexdump -v -e '5/1 "%02x""\n"' /dev/urandom |
  awk -v OFS='\t' '
    NR == 1 { print "foo", "bar", "baz" }
    { print substr($0, 1, 8), substr($0, 9, 2), int(NR * 32768 * rand()) }' |
  head -n "$1" > my_csv.csv
```

This falls into three parts:

```
hexdump -v -e '5/1 "%02x""\n"' /dev/urandom
```

extracts from `/dev/urandom` sequences of five bytes and formats then as hexadecimal strings,

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    NR == 1 { print "foo", "bar", "baz" }
    { print substr($0, 1, 8), substr($0, 9, 2), int(NR * 32768 * rand()) }'
```

formats the lines appropriately while adding a field that is the equivalent of `$(($i * $RANDOM))` and a header line, and

```
head -n "$1"
```

takes the first `$1` lines of this. When `head` quits, the pipe to awk is closed, `awk` quits, the pipe to `hexdump` is closed, and `hexdump` quits, so this makes the whole thing end at the right time.

On my machine (a Haswell i5), running this takes 0.83 seconds for a million lines.

Comment: amazing. my machine takes ~2 seconds for 1 mio lines....
just one question: why `int(NR * **65536** * rand())`?

Comment: awk's `rand()` function returns a value between 0 and 1, whereas bash's `$RANDOM` returns values between...0 and 32768, come to think of it. So that should be a 32768 instead of a 65536 there, and I'll fix that forthwith. `NR` is the number of the current line, so it's analogous to your `i`.

Comment: just used this today, very nice