# Append output of a command to each line in large file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I need to add a random guid to each line in a **large** text file.  I need that guid to be different for each line.

This works except that the guid is the same for every line:

```
sed -e "s/$/$(uuidgen -r)/" text1.log > text2.log
```

Comment: I ended up just writing a small c# program to do this for me and it took 10-20 seconds to run.  I'd recommend this over linux shell unless there's a better way than the answers below.

Comment: If you have GNU sed available, you can reevaluate `uuidgen` for every line like this: `sed 's/$/uuidgen -r/e'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the command substitution will get evaluated *before* the commands gets started.

The shell will first execute `uuidgen -r`, and replace the command substitution be it's result, let's say *0e4e5a48-82d1-43ea-94b6-c5de7573bdf8*. The shell will then execute `sed` like this:

```
sed -e "s/$/0e4e5a48-82d1-43ea-94b6-c5de7573bdf8/" text1.log > text2.log
```

You can use a *while* loop in the shell to achieve your goal:

```
while read -r line ; do
    echo "$line $(uuidgen -r)"
done < file > file_out
```

Comment: This is incredibly slow, unfortunately.  The input file is 200MB

Comment: Well, the main bottleneck is `uuidgen -r` here. It needs randomness, which needs to get produced by the system. Move your mouse! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it using `awk`:

```
awk -v cmd='uuidgen' 'NF{cmd | getline u; print $0, u > "test2.log"; close(cmd)}' test1.log
```

- Condition `NF` (or `NF > 0`) ensures we do it only for non-empty lines.
- Since we are calling `close(cmd)` each time there will be a new call to `uuidgen` for every record.

However since `uuidgen` is called for every non-empty line, it might be slow for huge files.

Comment: Well if uuidgen is indeed the bottleneck then there's nothing that can be done.  That's weird though.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than run a whole new `uuidgen` process for each and every line, I generated a new UUID for each line in **Perl** which is just a function call:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use UUID::Tiny ':std';

my $filename = 'data.txt';
open(my $fh,'<',$filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  my $uuid = create_uuid(UUID_V4);
  my $str  = uuid_to_string($uuid);
  print "$row $str\n";
}
```

To test, I generated a 1,000,000 line CSV as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29254156/2836621).

It takes 10 seconds to add the UUID to the end of each line of the 1,000,000 record file on my iMac.