# Can I use sed to generate UUIDs inline instead of echo?

Tags: bash, sed, uuid

This bash snippet works to add a UUID and a tab character (\t) at the start of each line of a file.

```
    while read; do
    echo "$(uuidgen | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')\t$REPLY"
    done < sourcefile.tsv > temp_destination.tsv
```

(Note the reason for the pipe to TR is to convert them to lowercase in MacOS version of UUID-generation).

Although that performs well for smaller files, it doesn't seem efficient.

```
sed -i '' "s/^/$(uuidgen | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')\t/" sourcefile.tsv
```

Again, using MacOS bash so the '' after the -i flag is required since I don't want a backup file.

I think sed would perform better, but I think I have to have the UUID generation in some sort of loop.

I'm just looking to make this faster and/or perform more efficiently. It's working, but it's pretty slow on a 20,000-line file, and all other attempts by me have stumped me.

EDIT: I tested my bash script just outputting the UUIDs to a while loop without any of the other subprocesses. With my configuration, I can generate about 250-300 per second, so updating a 20,000-line file will take a minimum of 72 seconds just because of the weak link of UUID generation. As described below, using Perl or Python will likely be faster.

EDIT 2: This little python script kill the bash script. This snippet only does part of what I need, but just for comparison, it generated about 200,000 UUIDs in a second, or 1,000,000 in 5 seconds compared to the 250-300 in the bash subprocess. Wow, what a difference.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#this generates 1,000,000 UUIDs in about 5 seconds

import uuid
import sys

sys.stdout = open('lots-of-uuid.txt', 'w')
i = 1
while i < 1000000:
    print(uuid.uuid4())
    i +=1 
sys.stdout.close()
```

Comment: Why do you say "it doesn't seem efficient"? In what way? You say "perform more efficiently" which is different than "faster", so how do you mean?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45492385/2836621

Comment: The `sed` version will prepend the same UUID to each line; do you want this, or do you want each line to get a different UUID? Also, in general the slowest operation in a shell script is creating subprocesses (i.e. to run commands); your first script looks like it'll create three processes per line: a subshell to handle the pipe inside `$( )`, and then that subshell will create subprocesses to run `uuidgen` and `tr`. If you want speed, it'd be best to switch to a language that can generate UUIDs by itself (without needing a subprocess), like perl or Python.

Comment: @AndyLester "faster" is definitely what I was trying to achieve. My perception of "doesn't seem efficient" would better be described more accurately as "slow."

Comment: @MarkSetchell that older post is helpful. It does seem Python or Perl will help tremendously here.

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes, I wanted a different UUID for each line, and I will look into perl and Python as an alternative to subprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that:

```
{
  uuidgen | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'
  echo -n "\t"
  cat 'sourcefile.tsv'
} > temp_destination.tsv
```

You may think it is not much different from your "read" version, but it is:

- You don't capture the result of `uuidgen`
- `cat` will probably perform faster than `read` + `$REPLY`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Using what you suggested, I only got one UUID on just that first line and not on any other lines, so I don't think this worked. I am trying to add a different UUID at the beginning of every single line in the file as the first field, followed by a tab character. So the output for each line changes from Field1 <tab> Field2 <tab> Filed3 <tab>. . .  to varying-uuid <tab> Field1 <tab> Field2 <tab> Filed3 <tab> . . .

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
while read; do printf "%s\t%s\n" $(uuidgen) "$REPLY"; done < input.tsv > output.tsv
```

No monkeying around with building strings.

Comment: I tried this suggestion, and the speed was essentially the same. The file was generated as desired with a different UUID on every line, but the speed was within 2 seconds of my version. Thanks, though!

Comment: How long does it take in your case, and how long do you want it to take?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -i '' 's/.*/printf &#;\Luuidgen/e;s/\([^#]*\)#\(.*\)/\2\t\1/' sourcefile.tsv
```

Comment: that's some impressive sed right there. Will see if I can parse it out for fun. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you  (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 'h;s/.*/uuidgen/e;s/.*/\L&/;G;s/\n/\t/' file
```

Make a copy of the current line.

Replace the current line by an evaluated `uuidgen` command and convert the result to lowercase.

Append the copy and replace the newline by a tab.